# Can we use AWS Spot instances for guaranteed mining profits?

Tags: amazon-web-services

By basic math, we can calculate the profitability of mining a specific coin in a mining pool. If we set the spot pricing limit to this value, will it not ensure that we make profits regardless? Also, no capex !

Comment: As commented the spot instances can be shut down whenever, you can be notified a minute upfront, so you could persist the work. Regardless that it's still some cryptocurrency, so nobody could guarantee you any profit

Comment: I am sorry and correct me if I am wrong, but in case of mining pools, you get paid based on the hashes you contribute. You dont have to be available for long enough and get paid depending on the hours ?

Comment: `you get paid based on the hashes you contribute` that's correct. There's probabilistic chance finding a valid hash. So it's up to your probability estimation if it will worth it. There is still some probability so nobody can *guarantee* the profitability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Spot Instances can be interrupted by EC2 with two minutes of notification when EC2 needs the capacity back.

That means that you still won't make profit regardless, because to mine some coin you need some time. Depending on the coin and instance type it may be from several minutes to several hours.
Spot instance can be interrupted any time, that means if it will be interrupted before you mine something - you payed for nothing.

Comment: I am sorry and correct me if I am wrong, but in case of mining pools, you get paid based on the hashes you contribute. You dont have to be available for long enough and get paid depending on the hours ?